# discord.py Level System (Add Roles)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want do add a Role which will gave to everyone who reach lvl 5. I already tried something but that didnt worked. Has somebody an idea how to start?

The stats got saved in a .json file like this:
{"719479402953572383": {"504641949068689430": {"experience": 8, "level": 1}}}

````
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot:
        print('function load')
        with open('level.json','r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
            print('file load')
        await update_data(users, message.author,message.guild)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 4, message.guild)
        await level_up(users, message.author,message.channel, message.guild)


        with open('level.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
    await bot.process_commands(message)



async def update_data(users, user,server):
    if not str(server.id) in users:
        users[str(server.id)] = {}
        if not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1
    elif not str(user.id) in users[str(server.id)]:
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] = 0
            users[str(server.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp, server):
  users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel, server):
  experience = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['experience']
  lvl_start = users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level']
  lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

  if str(user.guild.id) != '757383943116030074':
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
      await channel.send('{} has leveled up to Level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
      users[str(user.guild.id)][str(user.id)]['level'] = lvl_end```
````

Comment: You probably should not load the file for every message. Loading a file can take a long time and this might cause the bot to back up if there are a lot of messages in quick succession, plus the possibility of race conditions if you try to save a file while you are loading it.

Comment: As for your question, you will have to explain what you mean by "doesn't work". Are you getting an error, unexpected behavior, what happens exactly?

Comment: @mousetail loading a file for every command is not a problem, there are many bots that use json files for storing prefixes, it is fast enough

Comment: @Ceres Loading a file is pretty fast, but since you are doing it for every message, -even messages not addressed tot the bot- , I think race conditions are quite likely in a busy server. Best to cache the file contents and load it only periodically.

Comment: @mousetail I tried something but that doesnt worked (It was the false way) and now I dont know how to do it in anotherway. I ask if somebody knows how to code a role which gave to everyone who is lvl 5

Comment: @LaberlassFnm You still havn't explained what you mean by "doesn't work" or "false way"

Comment: @mousetail I dont know how to code such a thing. I tried it but that didnt worked (there wasnt any errors (i just coded garbage))

Comment: @Laberlass Ok, so what happened? Explain exactly what the behavior of your bot is and the expected behavior, as well as the difference.